as admin of a private company github repo and organization can i see if an employee cloned the repo?
As the admin of a company github organization can I see if someone clones the repo and any extra information like what machine they cloned on? Seems like it could be useful for security purposes.

I think you can probably find a record of it in the audit log.  It's quite extensive.

Here's a related question for AzDO which mentions GitHub in a comment to the answer, though not the specifics you desire. Perhaps GH enterprise has additional options.

Security? Shouldn’t the assumption just be that they are cloning it? push/pull/clone is the point of having access to it.

I do not have GitHub Enterprise so I cannot confirm, but this article seems to suggest that by default, IP addresses are not shown for audit logs. If you turn IP Addresses on:

GitHub Enterprise Cloud displays an IP address in the audit log when a member of the enterprise interacts with a resource owned by your enterprise or an organization in your enterprise. For example, you will see an IP address for audited events involving an internal or private repository owned by an organization in your enterprise, or resources associated with those repositories, such as an issue, pull request, action, or project.

Although cloning isn't specifically listed, my interpretation of "interacts" would include cloning. Once you enable this feature, it should be easy to confirm yourself by cloning a repo and checking the logs to see if the clone operation appears, and confirming that your machine's IP is listed. (It would not surprise me if the authenticated user is shown as well, if authentication is required for cloning.)
Here is a list of GitHub audit log events, of which one is git.clone.
